# C# - WindowsPhone - DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, arm, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage

I've just created a new empty project for Windows Phone 8.1 store app.
Then I added `WindowsAzure.Storage`.
When I'm trying to deploy this project to my real phone with selected options (Release, ARM), I get this error:

```
Error : DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004. See log file '...\obj\ARM\Release\MDIL\MDILXapCompileLog.txt' for more details.
```

Here's it:

```
Error: Compile filter argument specified non-existent file: C:\Users\vlad\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\obj\ARM\Release\MSIL\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll
Invalid argument

Microsoft (R) MDIL XAP Compiler - Version 4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Usage: MDILXAPCompile /In:<InputPath> /Out:<OutputPath> /Config:<ConfigPath> [/CompileFilter:<Assembly Path>;<Assembly Path>] [/Timeout:<Timeout>] [/Log:<LogPath>] [/AppX]

/In     - Path to directory containing files to process
/Out        - Path to directory to place processed files in
/Config     - Path to configuration file
/CompileFilter  - Optional restrictive list of assembly files in InputPath,
          separated by semi-colons, to be compiled.
/Timeout    - Optional timeout in milliseconds before killing the Crossgen process. Overrides config file timeout value. Use -1 for infinite timeout, 0 for application default (2 hours).
/Log        - Optional path to log file
/AppX       - Specifies that assemblies correspond to an AppX package

Relative paths are relative to this executable's directory.
```

I can deploy this app if I manually create folders for `de`, `es` etc. in `MSIL` folder and copying `Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll`, `Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll` and `System.Spatial.resources.dll` into each folder.

But when I call `await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(file);` my app just closing.
`try {} catch(Exception ex) {}` - no result.

App working excellent in Debug-x86 in Emulator, but why I cannot make this code running on ARM? How on earth I can use Azure with my app if I even cannot deploy it?

---

Looks like somewhere they use localization resources, but how I can fix it to make it available on ARM?

---

**UPD1** - this workaround make no sense - I have 4 exceptions.

```
string[] resourceBaseNames = new string[]
            {
                "System.Data.Services.Client",
                "Microsoft.Data.OData",
                "Microsoft.Data.Edm",
                "System.Spatial",
            };

            foreach(var baseName in resourceBaseNames)
            {
                string assemblyName = baseName;
                string resourceLoaderSuffix = ".TextRes";
                switch(baseName)
                {
                    case "System.Data.Services.Client":
                        assemblyName = "Microsoft.Data.Services.Client";
                        break;
                    case "Microsoft.Data.Edm":
                        resourceLoaderSuffix = ".EntityRes";
                        break;
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Assembly: {0}, baseName: {1}, suffix: {2}", assemblyName, baseName, resourceLoaderSuffix);

                try
                {
                    var type = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(assemblyName)).GetType(baseName + resourceLoaderSuffix);
                    WindowsRuntimeResourceManager.InjectIntoResxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass(type);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well, I have solution to deploy (but it is not fixed yet).
You should open `\obj\ARM\(Release|Debug)\MSIL\ ` and create all folders `de`, `es` etc. Copy files from `\packages\(Edb|OData|Services|Spatial)\lib\[lang]` to this folders.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the runtime itself actually which is hit by a Azure Storage dependency (OData library).

Please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/123 for more information about this bug and a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i removed unnecessary nuget packages (like **Microsoft.Data.OData**, **Microsoft.Data.Edm**, **Systen.Spatial**, **WindowsAzure.Storage**) from WP client and that error was resolved for me. You may wanna use Azure Storage Services from WP client. But i prefered to use restful web services instead of WP client. So i put Azure Storage codes to web services and i consumed those services from WP client.